# SPD Workflow doesn't create task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Good morning everyone,

i've created a simple approval workflow using SPD 2013. On a specfic step the workflow should create a task to be approved by a SharePoint user. When it comes to the assignment of the task the workflow stops with the following message:

```
Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: ContentTypeId at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at [...]
```

Permissions on the SP-Site are set to those who should use the workflow. The Workflow-App-Permission feature is enabled.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found out that this problem occurs because of some settings that have been made by the administartors. They played around with the website content types and website collumns and so my workflow wasn't working properly.